# Does Paypal sends the phone number of the user/payer in response, if yes then how can i get it?

Tags: paypal

I am making a simple paypal checkout and getting the response from the paypal after transaction in `POST` method to my `return` url. The response include everything I want but the **`phone/contact number`**.
I wanted to confirm if paypal does or doesn't share the contact/phone number and if it doesn't, can i have some official paypal link saying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login to your PayPal profile and enable "Require Phone Number".  It's under `profile->Website Payment Preferences->Contact Telephone Number`

Once you've got that setup it'll come back in the contact_phone phone parameter with IPN or PDT.

Comment: I will check with the live account but is there a way i can check it in a developer.paypal **[test account](https://developer.paypal.com/)**

Comment: Same way.  Login to the sandbox seller account and update the profile the same way.